# Is it possible to modify <text> inside <use> SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this model

```
<svg id=cardModel viewBox="0 0 100 200">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200" fill="transparent" stroke="black"></rect>
  <text id="text" x="25" y="125" font-size=100>change me</text>
</svg>
```

and I want to change the text from

```
<use href="#cardModel"></use>
```

I tryed using `getElementById` but as expected the `<use>` have no child.

Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6gh07fa/316/
*(seems like we can't use namespace in SO scripts)*

---

I know I could use [Node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) but I want to know if there is another way

Comment: getElementById("text") etc. but note that will change all the <use> instances.

Comment: thak you but, maybe I wasn't clear enought, the thing is I want each instance to have a different text

Comment: Then the answer is **no**.  The only way would be to duplicate the referenced SVG, change the `id`, change the text, and reference this new one.

Comment: In that case you should not be using <use> at all.

Comment: Thank you, I was almost sure I'd have this answer but still dreamed of some dark magic ^^